# Azure B2C Provider in DNN

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, dotnetnuke

i am using B2C provider for DNN and trying to install it as extension and it's throwing error https://i.stack.imgur.com/6faW1.png

i am trying to use multiple version as well but not installed properly and using source from https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.azureadb2cprovider/releases

Please help me out.

Comment: This sounds like an issue in the manifest file. I’ll check the package build and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in the DNN manifest file that has been solved on v1.4.7 (release https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.azureadb2cprovider/releases/tag/v1.4.7). Tracking the issue at https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.azureadb2cprovider/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer below before seeing this:  https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.azureadb2cprovider/issues/19

Perhaps this is pertinent to your question.  You might want to check with Ryan Moore (moorecreative" to see if he was able to resolve the issue.

---

First, please bear in mind that I am not familiar with this particular extension, but it seems as if it is "just another" authentication provide for DNN.

I'm also  a little confused.  The error message indicates that you've already installed th Intelequia AzureB2C provider.  Is that true?

You also say "I am using" and then "trying to install it as an extension."  If you are using it, that means that it is already installed as an extension, so a second attempt to install it should throw an error.  But, I would think that the installer should see that problem earlier in the process.

Finally, you say "i am trying to use multiple version as well."  A provider should be installed only once, and that is what the error message is telling you.

Once you have installed an authentication provider you typically enable it for a portal, and it becomes part of the authentication process.

You should read the documentation carefully, and make sure that you are trying to use the provider as the developer intended.

Comment: Whenever I am trying to install Intelequia AzureB2C provider extension then it's throwing error, after refreshing the page module B2C displaying in setting menu.
I am confuse it's proper install or not and whenever configure settings and trying to use then it's not working.

Can you please assist.

Comment: See the answer from David Rodriquez.